# How can I get Unity tweak tool themes and icons to load by default?

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. I've installed 15.10 on my laptop with unity tweak tool using the arc-dark theme as well as the Numix icons with no problems. It uses Intel graphics. On my [desktop](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/dM2FBm) using proprietary nvidia-352-updates driver. On my desktop, when I change the theme in unity tweak tool, it doesn't work completely, with the top windows bar with maximize minimize and close buttons staying the same as default theme. Icons won't change either. However, when I do `compiz --replace` in terminal it makes everything look proper. I've set Ubuntu to run that on start up but it doesn't work. I have to run it from terminal every time.